# Asynchronously generating Bearer token in `gatsby-source-graphql` headers option

Tags: graphql, config, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I would like to asynchronously generate an `Auth token` in `gatsby-source-graphq` headers option. According to documentation, I can use an async function to generate my `Bearer token` but I would also like to store it somewhere. I can't use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` because I don't have access to the window object in `gatsby-config.js`. Is there any way to achieve this? Here is my code:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

const axios = require("axios");

const getAuthToken = async () => {
  const token = btoa(
    `${process.env.CTP_CLIENT_ID}:${process.env.CTP_CLIENT_SECRET}`
  );
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      // I would like to save the Auth token here
      `${process.env.CTP_AUTH_URL}/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials`,
      null,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
    return `Bearer ${data.access_token}`;
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: "https://www.yourdomain.tld",
    title: "test_shop",
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss",
    "gatsby-plugin-image",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics",
      options: {
        trackingId: "test_shop",
      },
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        // Arbitrary name for the remote schema Query type
        typeName: "Merchant",
        // Field under which the remote schema will be accessible. You'll use this in your Gatsby query
        fieldName: "merchant",
        // Url to query from
        url: "https://api.europe-west1.gcp.commercetools.com/wj_trial/graphql",
        // TODO: add token dynamically
        headers: async () => {
          return {
            Authorization: await getAuthToken(),
          };
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: "./src/images/",
      },
      __key: "images",
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's achievable nor a good option. In fact, you are getting your token in the SSR (when the `gatsby-source-graphql` is triggered) and as you pointed, you don't have any tool available to store the response. This action will be always fired by you (or your company/client) when the project is built/deployed.

In your client-side (any React component), you know that any AJAX action will be triggered by the user or by any side-effect of your application, there you control the environment and, to me, it's the place where you should save your tokens, credentials, etc, in a cookie, `localStorage`, etc.

Mixing both tokens being different situations I don't think it's a good option because of its own behavior (triggered when the project is built vs triggered by the client-side).

So, answering your question, you should duplicate that part of the code (isolate it to a separate function and call it twice if needed).